# Access server through LAN while using internet on 3G

Tags: windows-7, networking, wireless-networking, internet, lan

I have a problem having my 3G and LAN connecting simultaneously. At work we are connected through LAN to a server, which has an internet connection and we also access our files from there.

I am trying to use software which needs cloud access to enable some features but our domain is blocking the connections to the servers that he software is trying to access, hence we cannot use it properly. We have spoken with our IT department and they refuse to unblock the sites for no good reason.

Our workaround is to connect through 3G to the internet but the issue is that we need to unplug the LAN otherwise the internet connection just comes from our server and nothing comes through the 3G modem.

Is it possible to connect to the internet through the 3G modem while still being connected to our servers with access to our files but without the domain restrictions?

A solution I tried was to change the **metric number** of the IPV4 property of the LAN to 2, but that did not work.

Your help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Did you change the metric of the 3G to 1 at the same time as changing the LAn adapter to 2? Also, why don't you bring up with the senior management of your company sorting out the IT team blocking access to legitimate business software (there must be a reason why they won't allow it)... usually a case to senior management should allow all sides to work out a solution...

Comment: Shortly after I posted the question I realized I was stupid and did not change the 3G metric number to 1. Though it did not work after I changed it anyway. On numerous accounts did our senior management (our director) contact the senior management of IT but to no avail. They keep saying they're skeptical about the reason why the software wants that access. It is very well known civil engineering software suites which access online map data etc. so it's not just something we pulled out of the air.